# how to programmatically, in Swift, set an uiimageview to the xcode built-in applewatch icon image?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

I like the watch icon you get when you use storyboard to add a UIIMAGEVIEW and set its Image attribute to the built-in "applewatch" icon.

But when I programmatically create a UIIMAGEVIEW how can I set it to that cool icon?

Here I add a 3rd party .png of a wrist band.   But I want to use the built-in which looks best:

```
let imageName = "Wrist Band.png"
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: Which apple watch image are you talking about?

Comment: The one you get from Storyboard > add UIImageView > select its Image View attribute in Attribute Inspecter and set to "applewatch".   (little blue watch with white screen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be talking about the [SF symbol](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/) `applewatch`. You can get that (or any other SF symbol) by using [`UIImage(systemName:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/3294233-init):

```
UIImage(systemName: "applewatch")
```

Notes:

- The color of the watch depends on the `tintColor` of the image view
- Available on iOS 14+

Comment: ...now I have to figure out how to do the imageView.frame = CGRect in my top app loop without tieing up viewDidLoad.

Comment: @DougNull why do I feel like you are doing something terribly wrong here? Have you not heard of “AutoLayout”?

Comment: Well, I'm not developing a full-blown app for multiple types of devices, just a proof-of-concept ASAP -- I repeat: ASAP -- to run only on an iPhone, and to just move multiple UIImageView's around the screen (a sort of dynamic map).  Will AutoLayout make doing that substantially faster than just a GCD task that moves UIImageView's around the screen?

Comment: Now with that context, you're right. Autolayout won't help you too much there. @DougNull